# How do I calculate what the exact difference in the x-values are in these two linear plots?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I'm at work and I'm kind of drawing a blank right now since it is a Monday morning. So we have these two plots and there's some variation in temperature (the x-values) going on here. How can I calculate the value? The pink plot is our ideal and good data, while the green plot is the part of the tool not performing as well and running at higher than expected temperature. I am trying to see the difference in (x-values) temperatures between the two plots when they have the y-value or Rs.I know I can horizontally take my cursor and make a rough estimate on the temperature and I can see they're off by 12 degrees. But how can I show this mathematically?
[Rs vs. Temp for two susceptors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgAaX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your problem right, you have the linear equation y=ax+b and y=cx+d, just modify for x=(y-b)/a and x=(y-d)/c and calculate the difference for equal y.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I was just being dumb haha for not realizing i could do that